# Git suddenly started to choke on “git pull” for only one repo

Tags: ssh, git, tortoise-git, pull

Yesterday, at some point in time, my *Git for Windows* suddenly started to choke (hang forever) on `git pull` for only one repo. I managed to pull changes ten times this day, I started to fail on eleventh pull.

Since the same happend to *TortoiseGit*, and after [doing](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SSHD-255) [some](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-3824) [research](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=1880), I narrowed the problem to *TortoisePlink* (used by *Git for Windows*) never exiting (both *Git for Windows* and *TortoiseGit* unhanged and continued normally, when I killed *TortoisePlink* using *Task Manager*).

I have updated services (including *Putty*) to newest version, applied [solution](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=1880#c25) and problem is now solved.

I understand, where problem originates and how to solve it. However, there are certain things, that I don't understand or even see them as weird, so I'd appreciate, if someone could shed some light on this case.

Accordind to [solution](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=1880#c25), problem is caused by some misunderstanding between SSH client and my Gerrit server. If that is true, then how it is possible that:

1. *Problem occurs only for `git pull`*. The `git push` and other remote-related, authentication-requiring commands works normally.
2. *Problem started to occur suddenly*. Yesterday, until 14:25 UTC, I was able to push/pull changes for this repo. I did around 10 pulls. And suddenly, without any change in my configuration, updating any software and actually doing anything else, my *git* started to choke on `git pull` (there were also no changes to server / Gerrit). And I wasn't able to pull anything until applying mentioned [solution](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=1880#c25).
3. *Problem occured to **one repo only***. Yes, *one repo*. I have another repo (another project) on the very same Gerrit server and I was able to pull / push everything without any problems, yesterday before / after choke on antoher repo and today before / after applying the solution.

If there are some changes / bugs in SSH layer (in general), then I really can't understand, how can they influent only: (a) one way (pull, push works), (b) one repo (other works) and (c) happen suddenly (all was working minutes before). Can someone enlighten me on this?